# SQL Server parameters and percentage increase

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would one use a parameter to increase orders on the `orderdetails` table by 10 percent?

I did something like: add parameter named `IncPercent` to the value of an order if the value of `IncPercent` is under 10%, or if `IncPercent` is 10% or over, add 10% to the value of an order for all orders in the 
`OrderDetails` table utilising IF/ELSE.*/

Code that I have so far I'm kinda stuck

```
Create procedure [spAddPercentage] 
     @incPercent decimal(5,4)
as
     update OrderDetails
     set @incPercent = @incpercent * 1.10 
     .........
```

I cannot figure out how to use the if else statement in this code. Can anyone give me a better understanding or give me a example on what I should add for if/else?

Comment: How are you determining what order to update if the `IncPercent` is under 10%?

Comment: Can you add some example data from the table OrderDetails before and after the stored proc is run?

Comment: Word of caution: a `decimal(5,4)` datatype has **5 digits total**, and thereof **4 after the decimal comma** - so this can store values from 0.0000 through 9.9999 - but nothing more. Are you aware of this, and is this OK for you? (you cannot e.g. store "10" or "20" in such a variable / parameter)

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/8b03871173e11f0e931bd0a0ab5dec20.png here is a screen shot of the table in question.

Comment: The problem with screenshots of your table is two fold. First, we don't have a table to work with to help us write a query that has been tested. Second, is we have no idea what the datatypes are and knowing that can be critical in many situations. You would be far better off posting the create table scripts an insert statements for sample data. Here is a great article that explains how to do all this. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/d95ff2c16d3d6acf866ff2373cdf84d7.png a better image of the table and everything else. current code https://gyazo.com/84f4cdd806e3ba41de0fb1df15c90ecb

Comment: Look at your current code....do you know what an IF/ELSE construct is supposed to do? It does one set of instructions when the IF is true. You are doing that outside the IF and then inside the true portion you have nothing. You should go back and look at your notes about how to use IF/ELSE

Comment: You should look at the documentation, it is very clear how this works. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using an IF/ELSE here seems like a more complicated way to accomplish this. A case expression would be much simpler.

```
update OrderDetails
set Value = Value * (1 + case when @incPercent < .1 then .1 else @incPercent end)
```

Comment: im only looking for the use of if/else

Comment: Why IF/ELSE? That is the wrong thing to use here. You have to create two statements instead of one and is a completely arbitrary requirement.

Comment: because the assignment asks me to. And my trainer won't even explain it. With him it's like talking to a brick wall.

Comment: So this is homework? Good luck. I am not going to code your homework for you.

Comment: could give me some examples on what im looking for i never asked you to i needed some examples my boy pretty please with cherries on top :3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is info on using IF ELSE

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182717.aspx